# Creating a function that can be called like the definite integral template (dintt)

Tags: input-alias

The definite integral template takes 4 arguments as can be seen here:

[image]

Is it possible to make a function that can be called in the same kind of way?

For example is it possible to make this call a function foo, like so:

[image]

Comment: There are topics how to work with interpretation. Here's how to create Alias: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {"test" -> 
    SubsuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"<", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", ">"}], 
     "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"]}]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like with the Notation package?

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!